# mismatched input in ANTLR4

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I'm new to ANTLR. I don't see any problem with my grammar, but when I run the parse tree, ANTLR gives me `mismatched input` message. Could anyone help me explain why I get that?

Here is my lexer

```
lexer grammar SynthtaxLexer;

FUN : 'fun' ;

ID : [a-zA-Z_]+ ;

COMMA : ',';
OPENPAREN : '(';
CLOSEPAREN : ')';
OPENBRACKET : '{';
CLOSEBRACKET : '}';

NEWLINE: ('\r' '\n'? | '\n') -> skip;
WS : [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

Here is my parser

```
parser grammar SynthtaxParser;

prog : function+ EOF;
function : funcDeclaration OPENBRACKET CLOSEBRACKET;
funcDeclaration : FUN ID OPENPAREN formalParameters? CLOSEPAREN;
formalParameters : ID (COMMA ID)*;
```

Here is how I run it

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "antlr4-runtime.h"
#include "libs/SynthtaxLexer.h"
#include "libs/SynthtaxParser.h"

using namespace antlr4;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  std::ifstream stream;
  stream.open("../test/mini.in");

  ANTLRInputStream input(stream);
  synthtax_antlr::SynthtaxLexer lexer(&input);
  CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);

  tokens.fill();
  for (auto token : tokens.getTokens()) {
    std::cout << token->toString() << '\n';
  }

  synthtax_antlr::SynthtaxParser parser(&tokens);

  tree::ParseTree *tree = parser.prog();
  std::cout << tree->toStringTree(&parser) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the input

```bash
fun myfunction () {}
```

This is the output

```bash
[@0,0:2='fun',<1>,1:0]
[@1,4:13='myfunction',<2>,1:4]
[@2,15:15='(',<4>,1:15]
[@3,16:16=')',<5>,1:16]
[@4,18:18='{',<6>,1:18]
[@5,19:19='}',<7>,1:19]
[@6,21:20='<EOF>',<-1>,2:0]
line 1:0 mismatched input 'fun' expecting FUN
(prog fun myfunction ( ) { })
```

I tried solving the problem with this mini version of my original grammar, but still no luck

Comment: getTokens() leaves the pointer to the input buffer at the EOF. Use lexer.reset() after printing the tokens. Some targets may not have the reset() method exposed.

Comment: Your parser grammar is not correct. You forgot to include the token vocab option in the parser. The parser cannot work without know what lexer it is supposed to use, because you use a split grammar, not a combined grammar. `options { tokenVocab=SynthtaxLexer; }`. The build should have outputted a half dozen warnings.

Comment: Oh! Adding `lexer.reset()` and `tokenVocab` works, and no warnings also. So the combining is the problem. Thank you @kaby76

Answer (score 0):

The input `fun myfunction () {}` is parsed just fine:

[image]

Perhaps the token stream is already consumed because you print them to the stdout. Try this:

```c
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  std::ifstream stream;
  stream.open("../test/mini.in");

  ANTLRInputStream input(stream);
  synthtax_antlr::SynthtaxLexer lexer(&input);
  CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);

  // tokens.fill();
  // for (auto token : tokens.getTokens()) {
  //   std::cout << token->toString() << '\n';
  // }

  synthtax_antlr::SynthtaxParser parser(&tokens);

  tree::ParseTree *tree = parser.prog();
  std::cout << tree->toStringTree(&parser) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

And if that doesn't work, make sure you've recently generated lexer- and parser classes from your grammar.

I tried the following Java code:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var lexer = new SynthtaxLexer(CharStreams.fromString("fun myfunction () {}"));
        var parser = new SynthtaxParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        var root = parser.prog();
        System.out.println(root.toStringTree(parser));
    }
}
```

which prints:

```
(prog (function (funcDeclaration fun myfunction ( )) { }) <EOF>)
```

Comment: I regenerated the lexer and parser classes, and ran your code. It still gives me an error
`line 1:0 mismatched input 'fun' expecting FUN`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the grammar.

Comment: Have you not shortened the grammar you posted here, and that your real grammar is different (larger)?

Comment: Yes, my real grammar is larger. But I'm working on the shorter grammar, the one I posted here, and it still doesn't work

Comment: I see your Java code works. Probably there's something wrong with the C++ runtime? This is my CMakeLists.txt https://ideone.com/w0nbRY

Comment: I also got `(prog fun myfunction ( ) { })` but before that line I got ` line 1:0 mismatched input 'fun' expecting FUN` Maybe that's not an error?

Comment: I don't know what is going wrong. I cannot imagine it's a bug in the C++ runtime though.

Comment: I do think the error comes from generated classes other than from the grammar you posted. The error suggests it comes from a grammar where the `FUN` token is placed _after_ the `ID` token. So if that is the case in your larger grammar, I am fairly sure that you're still testing against generated classes from the larger grammar. Anyway, best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I also placed FUN before ID in my larger one but still didn't work. Well, I'll keep trying then

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `mismatched input` doesn't affect the correctness of my grammar at least. So the way I fixed it was to ignore it with `MyErrorStrategy` in main.cpp

```c
#include "antlr4-runtime.h"
// other includes ...

using namespace antlr4; 

class MyErrorStrategy : public DefaultErrorStrategy { 
public:
  virtual void reportInputMismatch(Parser *recognizer, const InputMismatchException &e) {
    // Do nothing to ignore input mismatch errors
  }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  // ...
  synthtax_antlr::SynthtaxParser parser(&tokens);

  parser.setErrorHandler(std::make_shared<MyErrorStrategy>());

  tree::ParseTree *tree = parser.prog();
  std::cout << tree->toStringTree(&parser) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I don't recommend this. Covering up a bug in the grammar is not going to help you find out why the tree (`(prog fun myfunction ( ) { })`) is incorrect.